# Trying to make copy of table using subquery

Tags: database, oracle

SO I am trying to make a copy of a table I just created. I named it grad candidates. Using what I know so far this is how it should look like. I want to name the copy of the table harmeier.

```
CREATE TABLE harmeier
AS (SELECT student_id, last_name, first_name, credits, graduation_date)
FROM grad_candidates;
```

Its giving me error saying FROM keyword not found where expected.

Comment: remove the brackets around the select

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are the problem. Just get rid of them and you'll be all set:

```
CREATE TABLE harmeier
AS SELECT student_id, last_name, first_name, credits, graduation_date
FROM grad_candidates; -- no parentheses at all
```

Or place them around the *entire* query if you prefer; either way the result will be identical:

```
CREATE TABLE harmeier
AS (SELECT student_id, last_name, first_name, credits, graduation_date
FROM grad_candidates);  -- or parentheses around the entire query
```